# Ionic 2: Use fingerprint to sign in to app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, touch-id, ionic-native

I have an Ionic 2 app that connects to an API that has a user database.  Is there a way to add fingerprint data to my database to enable a user to sign in with their fingerprint rather than a username and password?

All fingerprint solutions I've seen seem to rely on the device owner, not a database of users.